# Ruby Testing: How do I use the same instance of Sequel in my tests?

Tags: ruby, testing, constants, sequel

I have a module defined along the following lines:

```
module SomeModule
  DB   = Sequel.connect("sqlite://database.db")
end
```

I'm using `aruba` (i.e. `cucumber`) in my tests, as this module is a CLI application.

My problem is that when I add a record using the CLI, I am unable to see that record in my tests.

The apparent reason for this is that my tests and the CLI app are not using the same instance of Sequel, and therefore, updates done from CLI are not being seen by the tests, or so it seems.

When I redeclare the `DB`'s value, I can instantly see my new records. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? And, how someone will usually approach the Sequel tests?

---

**UPDATE**:

I can confirm that the objects are different. I get different `SomeModule::DB.object_id` for both cases:

```
  70261673298620
  70361073575380
```

Comment: I think the test database is wiped on each test run.

Comment: @Threeve: I confirmed, and seems that the database exists.